# git - how to delete local master if you have no other branches

Tags: git

*EDIT: The intent is to do a completely clean reset of my local copy of master, to remote master. I prefer to reset to remote, over `$ git reset --hard HEAD`, which I've found on occasion gives me issues.*

I know I can delete a local git branch like so:

```
$ git branch -D master
```

but is there a way to do that if you have no other branches? as git won't let you delete the branch you're currently on.

Normally I'd just switch into another branch, but what if you have no other branches? Create a temporary branch?

NOTE: not quite a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12606612/26510), I believe

Comment: Why would you do something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't deleting master basically delete your whole repo? Couldn't you just delete the `.git` folder for the same effect

Comment: You could create an empty-branch (eg. like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100048/create-empty-branch-on-github/55943394) and then delete master. Still the question, why this would be useful is open.

Comment: "The intent is to do a completely clean reset of my local copy of master, to remote master" I don't get why you wouldn't just throw the whole folder away and reclone the remote.

Comment: I think that either resetting or @matt's suggestion is the most adequate solution. Everything else would be a hackfix.

Comment: I like to script everything, so I want a script that can do this against any repo, regardless of the repos size...  Revert it, no matter what, as fast as possible, with no left overs... I didnt expect this would have any real answers, other than do `git reset --hard origin/master` instead.

Comment: If you are to also put this into a script, then the easiest should be to just hardcode the reset command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be exactly what you want, but if the question is "how do I delete my only git branch" then I think this answer might meet those requirements:

```
mkdir deleteme
cd deleteme
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in deleteme/.git/
git:(master) echo foo > bar.txt
git:(master) ✗ git add -A
git:(master) ✗ git commit -m 'initial commit'
[master (root-commit) 2dc7ccd] initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 bar.txt
git:(master) git checkout 2dc7ccd
HEAD is now at 2dc7ccd initial commit
git:(2dc7ccd) git branch -D master
Deleted branch master (was 2dc7ccd).
git:(2dc7ccd) git branch -l
* (HEAD detached at 11c60ce)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants either, but I'm upvoting because it highlights the fact that you can delete even the last branch. I suspect after deleting `master`, OP would go checkout `master` again from the remote. And btw, I don't think you even have to tag it. You could simplify this by checking out the top commit by ID. (And I just linked my answer to yours because I like your point.)

Comment: I updated the answer to not tag it - you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You always have to have *something* checked out (unless you make a bare repo for sharing purposes only which you won't be working out of). In your case, if `master` is the only branch left, that's your current branch and you can't delete it (yet). You could create or checkout another branch if you really want to, or even [detach to a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708666/184546) instead of a branch name, and then delete `master`. Or,

> I prefer to reset to remote...

[That is exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210446/184546) what I would do:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard @{u}
```

With `master` checked out and tracking `origin/master` that would be the same command as:

`git reset --hard origin/master`

From there, you can [wipe out your non-tracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61212/184546) too if you'd like.

Alternatively, since you have only one branch and you don't like what you have on it, this is a pretty good candidate for deleting your repo and re-cloning. For a sufficiently small repo that is what I'd do, otherwise, I'd just reset my branch to the remote.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just delete everything from your branch, then you can do something like this at your local repository

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rm -r folder-name or rm <file1> <file2> <file3>…
$ git commit -m "Remove files"
$ git push origin master
```

Another option is to just delete your `.git` folder

Comment: I have added some clarification to the question, since you answered - please see the `EDIT:` comment in the original question. Thanks!